# Replacing all special characters, numbers and alphabets

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

This is the code for example

```
String a="abcd ABCD 0123 !@#$%^&*()";
```

This is syntax for replacing numbers & alphabets with blank

```
a = a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]","");
```

This is syntax for replacing special characters with blank

```
a = a.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-_]","");
```

So how do I combine both of these syntax to replace special characters, numbers and alphabets with blank without using this method `a = a.replaceAll(".","");` to replace entire string with blank?

Is there any other way ??

Comment: What is your expected output after this replacement?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to combine two character sets you can

- use `OR` operator like `[oneSet]|[secondSet]`
- place them in other set like `[[oneSet][secondSet]]`

  - which can also be simplified to `[oneSet[secondSet]]` so maybe you are looking for something like

```
a = a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9[^\\w\\s-_]]","");
```

---

Demo: I will replace found characters with `X` to show exactly which characters ware replaced

```
String a = "abcd ABCD 0123 !@#$%^&*()";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "X"));
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-_]", "X"));
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9[^\\w\\s-_]]", "X"));
```

Output:

```
XXXX XXXX XXXX !@#$%^&*()
abcd ABCD 0123 XXXXXXXXXX
XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,sorry if my question was confusing,it was just to satisfy my curiosity, because until & unless i solve my doubts, i cannot move ahead.

Comment: for this "[^\\w\\s-_]" expression,  _- is not being remove. how do i remove _- ?

Comment: @phongyewtong Check `[^\\w\\s-]|_`.

Answer (score 0):

Combine with `|`:

```
a=a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]|[^\\w\\s-_]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use below to account for line-breaks

```
String s = "abcd ABCD 0123 !@#$%^&*()";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)."," "));
```